# Getting query length with Ajax / Django

Tags: django, ajax, django-ajax-selects

According to the selection in the form, I want to get the number of records that match the id of the selected data as an integer.

Here is my view :

```
def loadRelationalForm(request):
    main_task_id = request.GET.get('main_task_id')
    relational_tasks = TaskTypeRelations.objects.filter(main_task_type_id = main_task_id)
    data_len = len(relational_tasks)


    return JsonResponse({'data': data_len})
```

Here is my ajax :

```
<script>
$("#id_user_task-0-task_types_id").change(function () {
    const url = $("#usertask-form").attr("data-relationalform-url");  
    const mainTaskId = $(this).val();  
    
    $.ajax({                    
        url: url,                 
        data: {
            'main_task_id': mainTaskId,             
        },
        success: function (resp) {  
           console.log(resp.data);
        }
    });

});
```

I want to write the number of relational tasks associated with the `main_task_id` of the selected data in the form. But I couldn't do it. Thanks for your help. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data you're pulling is an integer.
This line :

```py
 main_task_id = request.GET.get('main_task_id')
```

Might be a string, and the resulting query would find no match.

Aside, if you want a number of related objects, you have more efficients way to do it :

```py
def loadRelationalForm(request):
    main_task_id = request.GET.get('main_task_id')
    if main_task_id:
        main_task_id = int(main_task_id)

    main_task = TheMainTaskModel.objects.get(id=main_task_id)
    related_task_count = main_task.tasktyperelations_set.count()


    return JsonResponse({'data': related_task_count})
```

See doc about [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) and .[count()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.count)

Comment: I get undefined error when I make a selection. I know about "reverse relationship". Do I need to make corrections on the Ajax side?

Comment: What do you mean by "undefined error" ? What do you mean by "selection" ?

Comment: after selection console.log output  is "undefined" not returning the length of the query. I think there are some places I need to fix on the ajax side. I still haven't fixed the problem.

Comment: Is everything looking good before returning? In your example, is `data_len` having the proper value?